# Explain ClickableViewAccessibility

Tags: android, warnings, accessibility, android-lint

Concerning [the SO swipe code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19506010/1587329), Android lint gave the warning

> OnSwipeTouchListener#onTouch should call View#performClick when a click is detected [ClickableViewAccessibility]

In the [description of the warning](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks), it says:

> If a View that overrides onTouchEvent or uses an OnTouchListener does not also
>   implement performClick and call it when clicks are detected, the View may not
>   handle accessibility actions properly. Logic handling the click actions should
>   ideally be placed in View#performClick as some accessibility services invoke
>   performClick when a click action should occur.

How do you "handle accessibility actions properly"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The warning arises because the code listens for `onTouchEvent` (see [docs, point 3](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/checklist.html#special-cases)). There is a pointer to a [solution for a click event](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/custom-views.html#custom-touch-events), but that does not address whether a swipe needs to be handled or not.

A workaround would be to use buttons that trigger the same action as the swipe event. Then, to use `@SuppressWarnings`.

Comment: This is only a workaround. Alternatives are welcome.